# An exception occurred after the Android project added aar？

Tags: android

An exception occurred after the Android project added aar？

```
compile(name: 'ftconsult-tv', ext: 'aar')
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope
Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope'
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' 
    compile files('libs/alitvpaylib.jar')
  //  compile files('libs/ksoap2-3.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0.jar')
  //  compile(name: 'mylibrary2-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'ftconsult-tv', ext: 'aar')
}